# Set prefered operator when more than one are suitable

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std

I have a class named `mc_int` which is actually a int, with some special abilities. It has set `operator int()`:

```
mc_int::operator int() {
        return value;   //int mc_int::value - the real int value of the class
}
```

But when I try to `cout<<` the class, I must always cast the class to int (`cout<<(int)mc_int_instance`, because I get the error:

> More than one operator "<<" matches these operands.

As well, this may be caused by the fact, that the **class also has** `<<` operator defined. What to do here?

Comment: Which operator do you want to be called?

Comment: What to do?  Get rid of the class entirely, and implement your "special abilities" as free functions acting on ints.

Comment: What other operators your class has overloaded?

Comment: Actually g++ [doesn't give me that error](http://pastebin.com/DQASSdZM).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley maybe its not that simple. I have a reason for using class of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11, you can make use of the `explicit` keyword to make it so you have to explicitly convert to `int`. More information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
explicit mc_int::operator int()
```

Now when you use it should use the `<<` operator method you defined and it should no longer be ambiguous to the compiler. If you do want to use the int, just cast to it like you did or with `static_cast<int>(the_object)`.